# Trying to square every digit of a number, but my algorithm is not working?

Tags: javascript, math

I'm trying to square every digit of a number;
for example:

123 should return 149

983 --> 81649 and so on

I messed it up somewhere in the following Javascript code and I'm looking for some guidance.

```
function splitNumber(num){
  var arr = [];
  while(num>0){
  var c = num%10;
  arr[arr.length]=c;
  num=num/10;}
  return arr;
}


function squareArrToNumber(arr){
  var c = 0;
  for(var i=arr.length-1;i>=0;i--){
  arr[i]=arr[i]^2;
  if(arr[i]^2>10)
  c = c*100+arr[i];
    else
  c = c*10+arr[i];
  }
  return c;
}

function squareDigits(num){
  squareArrToNumber(splitNumber(num));

}
```

Comment: Post sample input and expected output as well as what you get and what's wrong with it in clearer format when asking a question. But the problem is that you are trying to do squaring twice and using the wrong operator

Comment: `x ^ 2` is not square - it's the bitwise XOR operation. Try using `arr[i] * arr[i]` instead.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I made the `arr[i]* = arr[i]` and `if(arr[i]>10)` changes but i still get _undefined_ as an output for `squareDigits(234)`

Comment: You're not returning anything from that function - `return squareArrToNumber(splitNumber(num))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try out this code

```
function numToSqr(num){
    var i, sqr=[],n;
    num = num.toString();
    for(i=0;i<num.length;i++){
        n = Number(num[i]);
    sqr.push(n*n);
    }
    return Number(sqr.join(""));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple things wrong with your code, starting with an overcomplication to split a string of numbers into its consituant characters just use `.splt("")`:

```js
var str = "123";
var arr = str.split("");
for(var i = 0;i<arr.length;i++)
  alert(arr[i]);
```

Next, the code `num ^ 2` does not square a number. To do a square, simply multiply a number by itself (`num * num`)

This leaves us with a rather simple solution

```js
function splitNumber(num){
  return num.split("");
}

function joinArray(arr){
   return arr.join("");  
}

function squareArrToNumber(arr){
  var newArr = [];
  for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
      newArr.push(arr[i] * arr[i]);  
  }
  return joinArray(newArr);
}

function squareDigits(num){
  return squareArrToNumber(splitNumber(num));

}

alert(squareDigits("123"));
alert(squareDigits("983"));
```

Comment: yes, you were right! thanks for bearing with me..and also thanks for the awesome review. :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would do such a thing:

```
var num = 123;
var numArray = num.toString().split("");
var result = "";
for(var i = 0; i < numArray.length; i++){
   result += parseInt(numArray[i]) * parseInt(numArray[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function squareNum(number) {
  var array = [];
  // Split number into an array of numbers that make it up
  array = String(number).split('');

  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    // Take each number in that array and square it (in place)
    // Also can be done with forEach depending on what es version you're targetting
    array[i] = Math.pow(array[i], 2);
  }

  // combine and return the elements of the array
  return Number(array.join(''));
}

squareNum(123);
squareNum(983);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this example

```js
function squareDigits(n) {
    return +(n.toString().split('').map(val => val * val).join(''));
}
console.log(squareDigits(4444));
```

here **+** sign is convert the string into an integer.

Answer (score -1):

```
if(arr[i]^2>10)
```

should be

```
if(arr[i]>10)
```

And, as @Luaan noted, it should be

```
arr[i] *= arr[i]
```